# The operating system keeps freezing randomly

Tags: linux-mint

The operating system keeps freezing randomly, none of the short-keys works, I need to reboot via power button.

### What have I done

- I have already tested memory with MemTest86,
- I checked all the drives with `badsectors`,
- I already rolled back the kernel one version,
- I disabled Secure Boot in Bios,
- I already used Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Linux Mint Cinnamon 20 (all with the same pen drive)

but the OS keeps freezing randomly after a while.

I checked the journalctl and got this log (when it freezes I can only reboot via power button)

```
$ journalctl -p 3

Dec 29 09:33:32 toshiba kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Dec 29 09:33:32 toshiba kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-22).
Dec 29 09:33:32 toshiba kernel: [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xCAFEDEAD)
Dec 29 09:33:32 toshiba kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: disabling GPU acceleration
Dec 29 09:33:32 toshiba kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
Dec 29 09:33:32 toshiba kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
-- Reboot --
Dec 29 10:02:55 toshiba kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Dec 29 10:02:55 toshiba kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
Dec 29 10:02:55 toshiba kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
Dec 29 10:02:57 toshiba kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
-- Reboot --
Dec 29 10:12:04 toshiba kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Dec 29 10:12:04 toshiba kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
Dec 29 10:12:04 toshiba kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
Dec 29 10:12:04 toshiba kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
-- Reboot --
Dec 29 12:39:16 toshiba kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Dec 29 12:39:16 toshiba kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
Dec 29 12:39:16 toshiba kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
Dec 29 12:39:17 toshiba kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
Dec 29 12:46:05 toshiba pulseaudio[15041]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.ShuttingDown: Refusing activation, D-Bus is shutting down.
-- Reboot --
Dec 29 12:46:22 toshiba kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Dec 29 12:46:22 toshiba kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
Dec 29 12:46:22 toshiba kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
-- Reboot --
Dec 29 13:28:17 toshiba kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Dec 29 13:28:18 toshiba kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
Dec 29 13:28:18 toshiba kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
Dec 29 13:28:18 toshiba kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.2
Release:    20.2
Codename:   uma
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux toshiba 5.4.0-90-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 15 20:00:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for joao:               
Disk /dev/sdb: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 885CBAC4-8139-4C3B-BF89-DF4892FE0A92

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000LM003 HN-M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CD9751AE-10E0-4FDF-BA51-4A22851EA6C3

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1,8T Linux filesystem
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
[sudo] password for joao:               
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: Display controller
       product: Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c0000000-c003ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0040000-c005ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c1000000-c13fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Could you kindly help? I'm getting desperate since I'm stuck with this for 3 days. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try runing kernel 5.15.12

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I already tried several kernels, the same problem

Comment: Try running Windows 10 Enterprise ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise ) on it which can be used for free for up to 180 days. If it works, it indicates an issue with the Linux kernel which warrants a bug report, if it doesn't your HW is most likely broken.

Comment: That notebook has two video cards, an Intel and a Radeon. Radeons are known to be problematic. Late to the party ;) you could have had the Radeon one blacklisted at kernel level, did the same on my corporate Lenovo. The errors you show also hint you might need a firmware upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like a faulty video card.

ACPI (power management) is trying to get response from the PCI0 interface and fails. The PCI0 is usually a video...

Comment: indeed the freeze triggers when I do `sudo lspci`. How can I handle the issue? It's simply hardware? How can I be sure?

Comment: I added the output of `sudo lshw -c display`, please help `:)`

Comment: Just replace the video card.

Comment: It's a laptop, I can't